# Classification of int and string txt throws ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

**I am fairly new to Machine Learning, sorry in advance
I am trying to read from a txt file which has train samples as such:**

123 this is a long text string

325 another text

**and my labels.txt file is as such:**

123 1

325 2

**So after many tries I've managed to read them with pandas:**

```
train_labels = pd.read_csv('train_labels.txt', nrows=200, dtype=str, delimiter="\t", header=None)

train_samples = pd.read_csv('train_samples.txt', nrows=200, dtype=str, encoding="UTF-8", delimiter="\t", header=None)
```

**And I convert the string column in my train samples with vectorizer**

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

tfidfconverter = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=1500, min_df=5, max_df=0.7, stop_words=stop_words)

X = tfidfconverter.fit_transform(train_samples.iloc[:, 1]).toarray()
```

**Then I try to fit my classificator with random forest**

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000, random_state=0)

clf.fit(X, train_labels) -> error
```

**Then I read samples to calculate my accuracy score**

```
validation_source_samples = pd.read_csv('validation_source_samples.txt', nrows=200, dtype=str, encoding="UTF-8", delimiter="\t", header=None)

validation_source_labels = pd.read_csv('validation_source_labels.txt', nrows=200, dtype=str, delimiter="\t", header=None)

T = tfidfconverter.fit_transform(validation_source_samples.iloc[:, 1]).toarray()


pred = clf.predict(T)
```

on `clf.predict` I get the error:

```
`ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input`.
```

Model n_features is 780 and input n_features is 879

I have searched for answers on this type of error but nothing seemed to match my actual input files and problem. Sorry in advance if it has been answered before.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you fit the vectorizer **again** on the validation data, while the model learned the fit vectorizer from the train data, you can fix it by changing the `fit_transform` on the validation line to `transform` like this:

```
T = tfidfconverter.transform(validation_source_samples.iloc[:, 1]).toarray()
```

Comment: I see! This has solved the error,but I seem to get my prediction model with the ids from the first train_samples/labels, not the set I test on (validation..)

Comment: are you sure? how do you know that?